# Typescript: how to check class functions are bound when passing them around

Tags: typescript, function-binding

I'm a typescript newbie and I'm just learning about the `--noImplicitThis` compile flag from the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters), but I have come across a case that doesn't seem to behave in a way I would expect, could someone please help explain how I can correctly type check bound functions:

So using a similar example to the docs; the following code give me a type error despite executing correctly (if the type checking is skipped):

```js
type Card = {
    suit: string;
    card: number;
}

class Deck {
    suits: string[];
    cards: number[];

    constructor() {
        this.suits = ["hearts", "spades", "clubs", "diamonds"];
        this.cards = Array(52);
    }

    cardPicker(this: Deck): Card {
        const pickedCard: number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);
        const pickedSuit: number = Math.floor(pickedCard / 13);

        return { suit: this.suits[pickedSuit], card: pickedCard % 13 };
    }
}

// this could be a function that takes a callback as an
// argument, i.e. onClick
function runner(f: (this: Deck) => Card) : Card {
    return f();
}

const deck: Deck = new Deck()
const pickedCard: Card = runner(deck.cardPicker.bind(deck));
console.log("card: " + pickedCard.card + " of " + pickedCard.suit);
```

I have two related problems:

Firstly, with the code above:

I get a type error on `f()` in the `runner` function despite that function's `this` being correctly bound:

`The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Deck'`

---

Secondly, to make the code pass typechecking I can modify the code by changing the `runner` function to:

```
function runner(f: () => Card) : Card {
    return f();
}
```

but then if I were to (accidently) unbind the function that is passed into the `runner`:

```
const pickedCard: Card = runner(deck.cardPicker);
```

I don't get a compilation error, when I really would like one as the code now does not execute correctly.

---

Is there a way for typescript to ensure that class functions are bound before passing them around?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an arrow function if you want to capture the scope (including **this**):

```
public cardPicker = () => {
    const pickedCard: number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);
    const pickedSuit: number = Math.floor(pickedCard / 13);

    return { suit: this.suits[pickedSuit], card: pickedCard % 13 };
}
[...]
const pickedCard: Card = runner(deck.cardPicker);
```

[Playground link with the full code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgJwCZQLxQN4Cgq6gZwFcBLYALgOAWIDsBzAbhzwGNEkKbCBbAIwgRMAvliwsANnHz4oAEQgsA1pma4ipfBXxVadANoBdJnihtkmqFz4DDTVaYD2NbQkItgDhAAoAlCpMmwAAWxPgAdOrAMuh6AERBEIhRsQA0ULH4YHBIEPip6RKEvHlpsUjEcNxOSHlG9oEh4WY1aFAAgggIcCBeAKwATD7GeCL2YEXixCym7AAKU4oCrb5oAHz%20AbgsTtpQYAsQSPDInDz8CK0AsnDBYQBm4g6eXte3XTRIDtwrAFRQA0N6qwdsA9gckABlEjkSxnJboV5Be6PZ77JSHY4oAD0UAAjABmQFA3AICDAQgIGiYAjQijBUIRaH4PRoxaQ6EGNLNCisjHsKAAUjx%20KgQmGuBEozuhBo7mITigrhoNAEXjuFBWqHWmL8FExGxJZIpVLuvmEom2zlBOSUFHkSlaKoA7nIFIpfGIQWD0Ud2Hr%20eglSrvDbFGFmvN0QhAZb8A5xBAwo86F5Ytz0lAANTetmY8P87OxKAOO4Z7O833IRmkIZAA)

Talking about architecture, I think cardPicker could be an external function taking a deck as an argument, it will be easier to test.

1st tip: Avoid using magic numbers.

2nd tip: Have a look at [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), you will be able to write: `` `card: ${pickedCard.card} of ${pickedCard.suit}` ``

Comment: Thanks I hadn't considered using an arrow function instead of a class method. Im not too sure what the other implications of doing this are though. I know that the function then becomes a property, which means the functions don't appear in the class prototype which seems to make mocking harder: https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1

Comment: Yes, that's why I added that part `I think cardPicker could be an external function taking a deck as an argument, it will be easier to test`